No overlap between real and synthetic data
I am using CVAE for synthetic data generation
I am trying to generate the synthetic data. My code is
import keras_tuner as kt
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.losses import mse
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# %%
data = pd.read_csv('train_data.csv')

#%%
# Preprocessing
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
features_columns = ['building_id', 'meter','site_id', 'square_feet', 'year_built', 'floor_count', 'air_temperature', 'cloud_coverage', 'dew_temperature', 'precip_depth_1_hr', 'sea_level_pressure', 'wind_direction', 'wind_speed']

scaled_features = scaler.fit_transform(data[features_columns])

# Splitting the data into training and testing sets (75% training, 25% testing)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(scaled_features, data['meter_reading'].values, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

# Label encoding for 'primary_use'
condition = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(data['primary_use'])
condition_train, condition_test = train_test_split(condition, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

# Define the CVAE model
input_dim = X_train.shape[1]
condition_dim = 1  # Since 'primary_use' is a single categorical encoded feature
intermediate_dim = 64  # Experiment with different intermediate dimensions
latent_dim = 10 # Reduced latent dimension for better manifold learning

inputs = Input(shape=(input_dim,))
conditions = Input(shape=(condition_dim,))
concat = Concatenate()([inputs, conditions])

h = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(concat)
z_mean = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_mean')(h)
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_log_var')(h)

def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    batch = K.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = K.int_shape(z_mean)[1]
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    return z_mean + K.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,))([z_mean, z_log_var])

decoder_h = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')
decoder_mean = Dense(input_dim, activation='sigmoid')
h_decoded = decoder_h(z)
x_decoded_mean = decoder_mean(h_decoded)

cvae = Model([inputs, conditions], x_decoded_mean)

reconstruction_loss = mse(inputs, x_decoded_mean) * input_dim
kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var)
kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
kl_loss *= -0.5
cvae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
cvae.add_loss(cvae_loss)

learning_rate = 1e-4
cvae.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate))

# Train the model
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)
history = cvae.fit([X_train, condition_train], epochs=30, batch_size=256, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping])

# Plot training and validation loss
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='Validation Loss')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss Over Epochs')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

for generation I am using
# Define Encoder
encoder = Model(inputs=cvae.input, outputs=[cvae.get_layer('z_mean').output, cvae.get_layer('z_log_var').output])

# Define Decoder
decoder_input = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='decoder_input')
decoder_hidden_layer = Dense(units=intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(decoder_input)
decoder_output_layer = Dense(units=input_dim, activation='linear')(decoder_hidden_layer)
decoder = Model(inputs=decoder_input, outputs=decoder_output_layer)

# Sample from the latent space and generate new data
def sample_latent_features(z_mean, z_log_var):
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(K.shape(z_mean)[0], K.int_shape(z_mean)[1]))
    return z_mean + K.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

z_mean, z_log_var = encoder.predict([X_test, condition_test])
z_sampled = sample_latent_features(z_mean, z_log_var)
X_test_generated = decoder.predict(K.eval(z_sampled))

# Scale back the generated features to the original scale
X_test_generated = scaler.inverse_transform(X_test_generated)

generated_meter_readings = X_test_generated[:, 0]  # Assuming 'meter_reading' is the first feature

#%%
# Append generated meter readings to the test data
generated_data = pd.DataFrame(X_test_generated, columns=features_columns)

# Add the generated meter readings as a new column
generated_data['generated_meter_reading'] = generated_meter_readings

# Add the 'primary_use' condition back to the generated data
generated_data['primary_use'] = condition_test 

# Save the generated data to a CSV file
generated_data.to_csv('Predictions.csv', index=False)

print("Generated data saved to 'Predictions.csv'.")

After generation I want to visualize the synthtetic data. But every time I got different distribution of the data.
For PCA and T-SNE I am using
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd

# Load your datasets
actual_data = pd.read_csv('train_data.csv')
CVAE_traditional = pd.read_csv('Predictions.csv')

# Select numerical columns for both datasets
actual_data_numeric = actual_data.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
CVAE_traditional_numeric = CVAE_traditional.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])

# Find common columns between the datasets
common_columns = actual_data_numeric.columns.intersection(CVAE_traditional_numeric.columns)

# Align datasets to these common columns
actual_data_aligned = actual_data_numeric[common_columns]
CVAE_traditional_aligned = CVAE_traditional_numeric[common_columns]

# Apply StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
actual_data_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(actual_data_aligned)
CVAE_traditional_scaled = scaler.transform(CVAE_traditional_aligned)

# Visualize PCA for both datasets
def visualize_pca(ori_data, gen_data, seed=42):
    """Using PCA for original and generated data visualization."""
    
    # Analysis sample size (for faster computation)
    anal_sample_no = min(1000, len(ori_data), len(gen_data))
    
    # Set the random seed for reproducibility
    np.random.seed(seed)
    
    # Sample the data
    ori_idx = np.random.permutation(len(ori_data))[:anal_sample_no]
    gen_idx = np.random.permutation(len(gen_data))[:anal_sample_no]
    ori_data_sampled = np.asarray(ori_data)[ori_idx]
    gen_data_sampled = np.asarray(gen_data)[gen_idx]
    
    # PCA Analysis
    pca = PCA(n_components=2, random_state=seed)
    pca_ori_results = pca.fit_transform(ori_data_sampled)
    pca_gen_results = pca.transform(gen_data_sampled)
    
    # Plotting
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.scatter(pca_ori_results[:, 0], pca_ori_results[:, 1], 
                c='red', alpha=0.5, label="Original")
    plt.scatter(pca_gen_results[:, 0], pca_gen_results[:, 1], 
                c='blue', alpha=0.5, label="Synthetic")
    
    plt.title('PCA Visualization')
    plt.xlabel('PCA Component 1')
    plt.ylabel('PCA Component 2')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
    plt.show()

# Visualize t-SNE for both datasets
def visualize_tsne(ori_data, gen_data, seed=42):
    """Using t-SNE for original and generated data visualization."""
    
    # Analysis sample size (for faster computation)
    anal_sample_no = min(1000, len(ori_data), len(gen_data))
    
    # Set the random seed for reproducibility
    np.random.seed(seed)
    
    # Sample the data
    ori_idx = np.random.permutation(len(ori_data))[:anal_sample_no]
    gen_idx = np.random.permutation(len(gen_data))[:anal_sample_no]
    ori_data_sampled = np.asarray(ori_data)[ori_idx]
    gen_data_sampled = np.asarray(gen_data)[gen_idx]
    
    # t-SNE Analysis
    tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=seed)
    tsne_results = tsne.fit_transform(np.vstack((ori_data_sampled, gen_data_sampled)))
    
    # Plotting
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.scatter(tsne_results[:anal_sample_no, 0], tsne_results[:anal_sample_no, 1], 
                c='red', alpha=0.5, label="Original")
    plt.scatter(tsne_results[anal_sample_no:, 0], tsne_results[anal_sample_no:, 1], 
                c='blue', alpha=0.5, label="Synthetic")
    
    plt.title('t-SNE Visualization')
    plt.xlabel('t-SNE Component 1')
    plt.ylabel('t-SNE Component 2')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
    plt.show()

# Visualize PCA
print("PCA Visualization:")
visualize_pca(actual_data_scaled, CVAE_traditional_scaled)

# Visualize t-SNE
print("t-SNE Visualization:")
visualize_tsne(actual_data_scaled, CVAE_traditional_scaled)

There is on overlap between real and synthetic data. Thats not good. So how can I solve this.
Any suggestions.
